# Remove items from multi select list on dbl click

Tags: knockout.js

Let's say we have to lists and copy items from one list to another and then regret and want to remove only the copied items on a double click or something like that.

EDIT: Is it possible to remove selected items in an multiple select list on double click by a property instead of index, ie. Name? The idea is to later implement a sort function and then the index will change.

The code looks like this:

```
var SProcsViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.storedProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "Sp1",
       Id: 1
   }, {
       Name: "Sp2",
       Id: 2
   }, {
       Name: "Sp3",
       Id: 3
   }, {
       Name: "Sp4",
       Id: 4
   }]);
   self.storedProceduresInDB2 = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "Sp3",
       Id: 3
   }, {
       Name: "Sp4",
       Id: 4
   }, {
       Name: "Sp7",
       Id: 7
   }, {
       Name: "Sp8",
       Id: 8
   }]);

   self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1 = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb2 = ko.observableArray();

   self.copyToDb2 = function () {
       var sprocs = [];
       console.log('self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1()', self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1());

       ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function (value) {
        // console.log('arrayForEach',value,self.storedProceduresInDB2);
       var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2(), function (item) {
          console.log('item in storedProceduresInDB2', value, item);
          return value.Id === item.Id;
        });

        if (!match) {
            console.log('No match, so add to sprocs', value);
            sprocs.push(value);
        } else {
            console.log('Match found for:', value);
        }

       });

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function (value) {
        console.log('storedProceduresInDB1', value);
    });


    console.log('sprocs', sprocs);

    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.storedProceduresInDB2, sprocs)
    console.log('sprocs', sprocs, 'storedProceduresInDB2', self.storedProceduresInDB2());


   };

   return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new SProcsViewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/37/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `event` binding to subscribe on the `dblclick` event of the select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" height="5" 
     data-bind=" options: storedProceduresInDB2, 
                 optionsText: 'Name', 
                 selectedOptions: selectedStoredProceduresInDb2, 
                 event: { dblclick: removeFromDb2 } "></select>
```

Then in the event handler you can access the currently selected index through the event object passed in the second argument and use the index to remove the clicked item from your array:

```
self.removeFromDb2 = function(item, event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.selectedIndex)
    self.storedProceduresInDB2.splice(event.currentTarget.selectedIndex, 1)
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VNpN/).

Through the `event` parameter you can also access the actually clicked `option` element where you can get the text of the element which is your `Name` property:

```
self.removeFromDb2 = function(item, event){
    self.storedProceduresInDB2.remove(function(item) {
        return item.Name == event.target.text;
    });
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d8Ut/).

Comment: Is it possible to remove item defined by property instead of index? ie. name property of the selected item? I'm about to implement a sort function and this wouldn't work then.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to remove item by Name, but this will only work if your item names are unique.

Comment: When i log in removeFromDb2 it says item= undefined.

Comment: Sorry, i was loggin wrong. :) I've tried the fiddle now and if i copy Sp1 i'am not able to remove it by double clicking on it in list2. event.target.text is undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/6d8Ut/1/

Comment: @Henrik sorry but I cannot repro your issue in the http://jsfiddle.net/6d8Ut/1/ if I copy SP1 I can delete without any problems using Chrome33. Which browser are you using?

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer. My application needs to be working in all browsers. :( In the logging it says that event.target.text is undefined.

Comment: I found out that IE does not have event.target. It uses srcElement instead.

Comment: You can use the `currentTarget` in IE and Chrome and with some additional jQuery it should work in both browsers: `self.removeFromDb2 = function(item, event){       
        self.storedProceduresInDB2.remove(function(item) {
            return item.Name == $(event.currentTarget).find("option:selected").text();
        });
    }` http://jsfiddle.net/ue34N/

Comment: That worked. Is it possible to only be able to remove those items who is copied and none of the others? by ie. comparing with storedProceduresInDB2Orig.

Comment: Yes, you can do any comparison in your remove function . Like compare the current element to the `storedProceduresInDB2Orig` or whatever other criteria you have. But this is now a completely different question... and you should ask it separately.

Comment: The lists contains existing stored procedures in database, and the client could be confused if you are able to remove items from the lists and Think that they removing them from the database also.